# I have tried to write a snippet given in the ontology tutorial api in Jena

Tags: api, jena, ontology

The Snippet is as follows:

```
static String personURI    = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith";
static String fullName     = "John Smith";

Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
Resource johnSmith = model.createResource(personURI);
johnSmith.addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName);
```

When the code is run, it gives the following errors:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/sabarish/workspace/apache-jena-2.7.2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/sabarish/Jena-2.6.4/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the error you're getting is not related to your code, apparently you have more than one logging framework included in your classpath. Check which libraries you're importing.

In the StackTrace you posted, you seem to have imported the log4j jars twice.

This is **NOT** related to yout question but...
I used Jena for a really cool project in my university as RDF/OWL API, If you plan to do serious reasoning over an OWL ontology, I would recommend you to use Pellet :).

I have some basic examples here if you want to check them out, I don't know if it will help you but it took me a couple of days to put everything together properly.
https://github.com/iferminm/ReasoningAndPersisting

Comment: I really need to do some good projects in semantic web.Can u pls recommend something and guide me??

Comment: Well, I did my dissertation on Semantic Web, you can download it from my github, the book is in spanish because i'm from Venezuela. What do you have in mind?, you have to learn how to use the tools first. There are some books that you can read: start with Programming the Semantic Web and Semantic Web Programming, and Semantic Web for the Working Ontologist is you want to go deeper with OWL and ontology modeling. You have to read A LOT.

Comment: Thank u sir.I'll definitely read a lot.I have a great interest over semantic web.Need to do some research on it.You said about tools.Can you please mention those tools?

Comment: First, you should read about the theory behind everything: ontology and knowledge modeling. Then, you can start to try some ontology editors, I really like Protègè, it is a RDF/OWL editor and comes with Fact++, Hermit and Pellet integration to reason over your models and test that you have no inconsistencies in your model. One you practice on modeling, you can start developing apps. Try Virtuoso for persistence and practice SPARQL queries. In python I use CherryPy for the app itself and sparql-wrapper to query. You can also try CubicWeb (Python)